# Update all posts - 25 000 posts in total

Tags: posts

I have about 25 000+ posts and I need to update all of them.

Main question is if this will make server/hosting down or break anything )

I found this code which goes in functions.php and works, but another problem here is that it sets same published date/time to all posts

```
function update_all_posts() {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'numberposts' => -1
        );
        $all_posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($all_posts as $single_post){
            $single_post->post_title = $single_post->post_title.'';
            wp_update_post( $single_post );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'update_all_posts' );
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to update. It looks like you are replacing the post_title with the current post_title. And there's an extra period just after the end of your first statement in the foreach. What is it that you want to update?

Comment: Your other problem is that by putting this in the functions.php file, it will run on every page load. That will update all the posts every time. Probably not what you planned. You need to run the function manually. And there are elements of the $single_post that will allow you to set (or not set) the post date stamp.

Comment: Loading that many posts will almost certainly crash your server. These kind of bulk updates are better done using WP-CLI and done in batches.

Comment: @RickHellewell I am trying to just update all posts which are 25000+ on my website

Comment: @Welcher any idea where should I start searching to find tutorials on how to do it?

Comment: Update what? What do you need to change on all 25K+ posts? The only thing you are doing with your code is to add a space character to the posts' title. And then that will change the last-update-date value of the post when you save the change. There is lots of google/bings/ducks about WP-CLI. Or even doing it via phpMyAdmin. But I'd test it on a backup copy of your database, because those things never work right the first time.

Comment: @RickHellewell I need to update all this posts for this plugin to pull all my images from posts and upload them on the server https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/